# SSIS- if data exists based on a select statement, then send the data via email else nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, email-attachments

I want to create a package where I want to see if the data exists in the select statement, then send an email along with the data(doesn't matter in which form- excel/text file) else nothing.

Could you please suggest what tasks I need to use in the package?
Basically doing T-sql to check if location changed of employees, if so, notify via email and providing the data that changed in the email.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an Execute SQL Task, to check if Data Exists and assign a Value to a Result Set.

*Example*

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE)
   SELECT 1 AS Result     
ELSE
   SELECT 0 AS Result
```

Then you should specify that the Execute SQL store the returned value in a single Row result set *[For more info refer to this link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)*

Then you should add precedence constraint with the following expression *(assuming that `@[User:ResultValue]` is the variable where ResultSet is stored)*

```
@[User:ResultValue] == 1
```

And You can refer to the following question for detailed answer about sending sql query result as mail

- [How do I send the result set from a query as an attachment in an email using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336220/how-do-i-send-the-result-set-from-a-query-as-an-attachment-in-an-email-using-ssi)

Comment: I am following all the instructions provided in the second link you provided but somehow, when I receive the email, in the email body-it says "User::QueryResult" instead of the columns with data. Am I missing somewhere? I need all the columns and the data in the email body. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336220/how-do-i-send-the-result-set-from-a-query-as-an-attachment-in-an-email-using-ssi

Comment: i think that you are missed something in the script task

Comment: I entered the same C# script code in the Edit Script. I am not sure if I need to provide something anywhere else. Do I need to provide in the ReadOnlyVariables, ReadWriteVariables or in Expressions tab? Sorry, I am not familiar with script task.

Comment: @GeetanjaliSachdeva to get more help just update your question and provide detailed information about what you have done until now and add some screenshots